# How to test Delete in Firebase Realtime Database Rules Playground

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase Realtime database console, I see two rules that are confusing to me. One is named "delete" and the other is "set". Below are two snips of the console:

[image: Delete in Rules]

[image: Delete in Rules Playground]

In the end, all I want to prevent anyone from deleting a node. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no `.delete` rule in Firebase Realtime Database security rules. If you want to allow/disallow deletes, you can use the `data` and `newData` variables. Check for an example the documentation on [existing data vs new data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#existing_data_vs_new_data).

To test deletion in the playground, you can set or update the value of a node to `null`. This also applies to any code that write through the API: setting a node to `null` deletes that node from the database.

Comment: If there is no .delete rule in Firebase Realtime Database security rules, then what am I seeing on the second image - I typed ".d" and intellisense display ".delete"? Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what the autocomplete is doing there, but there is no `.delete` rule in Firebase Realtime Database security rules. Also see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security

Comment: I'm still searching for what the .delete is for. Could be an undocumented feature? Surely, it is there for something.  Thank you!

Comment: As said: there is no meaning to `".delete"` in Firebase Realtime Database's security rules. At best it's a bug in the auto-complete logic.